# Is it Possible to open a popup with some kind of transition as we have transition in Screen

Tags: python, popup, kivy

Can we add any transition while opening Popup . Forexample when opening Screen we can  have 
transition = FallOutTransition() . Is it possible to do the same in case of popups .

If not : 
I was thinking to create a Custom Popup where i can use screen Class and give transistion to it but i am not able to figure it out . Anyone have any idea ? See Sample code below :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen,FallOutTransition
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class CPopup(Screen,Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.transition= FallOutTransition()
        #self.title = "i am popup ... lol"

class A(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.transition= FallOutTransition()
        self.add_widget(Label(text="I am label on the main Widget !"))
        popup = Popup(title="hello i am a simple Popup",content=Label(text="i am popup content"),size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.height, Window.width/4))
        popup.open()
        popup.bind(on_open=self.on_open)

    def on_open(self,instance):
        print "hi popup was opened"
        Clock.schedule_once(instance.dismiss,2)


# App Class
class MyJBApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition= FallOutTransition())
        sm.add_widget(A(name='A'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJBApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Forexample when opening Screen we can have transition = FallOutTransition()

This is done by the ScreenManager, not the Screen.

> If not : I was thinking to create a Custom Popup where i can use screen Class and give transistion to it but i am not able to figure it out .

This won't work unless you use a ScreenManager somehow.

The FallOutTransition you mention actually uses a shader effect, which is tricky to duplicate outside the screenmanager if you don't know what you're doing (not hard, but not really documented much either).

However, you can get almost the same effect by using normal kivy animations. You would start the popup slightly smaller than you really want, and with an opacity of 0, then animate its size to what you really want and its opacity to 1.